# Need Help Inserting data in two different tables SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I was wondering if you can insert data into one table and have it appear in a different table in SQL without inserting into the second table?

Comment: You could do this using a trigger.  However, more likely, you can just insert the data into one table and use a `join` to see it in query results.

Comment: Thank you I will look more into the triggers and try it out. I am new to sql so I'm still learning everything.

THANK YOU

Comment: Can you give a use case? It's easier to find best approach when there is a context available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small sample of how update a table with trigger

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a4f3/1)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `upd_table2` BEFORE INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.msg = concat(NEW.msg, ' was here'); /* update the value for table 1*/
  INSERT INTO table2 values (concat(NEW.msg, ' was here too')); /* insert to table 2*/
END//

INSERT INTO `table1`
  (`msg`)
VALUES
  ('juan'),
  ('peter')//
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger is the way to go, CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx